# Solving $2x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4 = z^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all integer pairs $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy $$2x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4 = z^2.$$

We can rewrite the given equation as $(x^2+y^2)^2+(x^2)^2 = z^2$. Thus, $(x^2+y^2,x^2,z)$ must be a Pythagorean triple. How do we continue?

Also, for $x = 0$ we get $y^4 = z^2$ and so $z = \pm y^2$. Can we show that $x$ must be $0$?

Comment: Pythagorean triples can be [parametrized](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m446-03/pl322/parametrization.html).

Comment: @user19405892 could you add the tag "diophantine-equations"? I think it's better when a question has more than one tag.

Comment: Doing modulo 3 and 5 should help in this question

Comment: @ArianaGrande How?. It is easy to prove that the given equation has no solutions when $x$ is odd working modulo $4$ and $8,$ but how is it helpful to consider the eq. mod $3$ and/or $5$?

Comment: WTF?, why was this question marked as a duplicate of a question that was asked after this one?